# Render identical text in all browsers

Tags: html, browser, fonts

I am stuck in a problem and require your guidance.
We want to display 100% same text in Mozilla, Chrome and IE11.... same word spacing, line height etc.
So far what I learned is all 3 browsers use different render engines and different font file extensions.
Is there anyway we can force all three browsers to use same font rendering engine or same font extension to achieve 100% accurate results?

Already tried the following trick in CSS but no result:

```
text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to control the rendering engine used is to make pre-rendered images of text and use those instead of real text. Use [alt attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute) on the images, so screen readers and search engines etc can make sense of it too.

Even with images, browsers on different systems may scale it slightly differently. You cannot guarantee every pixel will be identical (and you shouldn't try).

Comment: @AliKhan, this the correct answer anyway. The closest you can get without images is to use a downloadable font, but even then, details of font rendering will vary.